# Get-ChildItem wildcard for "subfolder at any depth" of a file system tree

Tags: powershell

I would like to get all the files of an specific extension within a specific subfolder/s but that can be located at any level within a file system, for instance

```
Get-ChildItem ".\Source\**\Release\*.nupkg" -recurse
```

The simple asterisk works but searching on the immediate level under Source, but does not looks deeper in the tree.

I am looking to get this list of files from the command:

```
.\Source\Level1\Release\a.nupkg
.\Source\Level1\bin\Release\b.nupkg
```

Is there any way to achive this?

**UPDATE**

The answer of @JaredPar worked like a charm!. But my ouput is:

Directory: D:\Source\Level1\Release

ode                LastWriteTime     Name
---                -------------     ----
a---        08/23/2013     16:02      a.nupkg

Directory: D:\Source\Level1\bin\Release

ode                LastWriteTime     Name
---                -------------     ----
a---        08/23/2013     16:02      b.nupkg

I need to get one list with all the files, not grouped by directory, as in:

ode                LastWriteTime     Name
---                -------------     ----
a---        08/23/2013     16:02      a.nupkg
a---        08/23/2013     16:02      b.nupkg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following

```
gci -re -attribute Directory Release | 
%{ gci $_ -re -in *.nupkg }
```

The first command will find all directory values with the name Release under the current path.  You can then search below those paths specifically for *.nupkg files

Comment: Thanks! With some minor adjustments, it worked  like a charm! I need a little bit more of help: I get the files listed under a directory "header", but I would like to get only list of all files in every directory withouth the directory header. How can I achieve this?

Comment: @Hernan i'm not quite sure what you mean by "without the directory header".  Can you elaborate?

Comment: wrap the gci cmdlet in parentheses then access the fullname property to return only that, e.g. `%{ (gci $_ -re -in *.nupkg).FullName }`