# Powershell Get-ChildItem wildcard in path?

Tags: powershell-4.0, get-childitem

Can a wildcard be put in a folder name mask? Or is it necessary to run `Get-ChildItem` twice, one for the direcdtories and a second for the path? Even with the code below, I'm getting no directories returned.

I think [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18446976/get-childitem-wildcard-for-subfolder-at-any-depth-of-a-file-system-tree) shows how to do it with the older syntax:

```cs
$folderName = "c:\BizTalk\Vendors\*\AS2FilesReceived\"
$folderMask = "$folderName\*.*" 
$dirs = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderName -Recurse -Directory 
Write-Host "Number of Matching Directories = $($dirs.Count)" 
$dirs 

#$files = $dirs | %{ Get-ChildItem -Path $folderMask -Filter "*.*" -Exclude "*997*.*" -File}  | Where-Object {$_.CreationTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-6)} | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ultimately, I just wanted the files, not sure if I had a typo or what, but now this works.  It's possible I swithced from `$folderMask` to `$folderName`, or didn't have the *.* on the end of the `$folderMask`.

```
$folderMask = "c:\BizTalk\Vendors\*\AS2FilesReceived\*.*"
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderMask -File  
Write-Host "Number of Matching Files = $($files.Count)"
```

Comment: If you want just the files...
`Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\BizTalk\Vendors\*\AS2FilesReceived\' -Directory | % {Get-ChildItem -Path $_ *.txt} | % {$_.FullName}`

Answer (score 4):

`Get-ChildItem` supports wildcards in the path, but the wildcard applies only to a single folder level, i.e. a pattern `C:\foo\*\bar` will find folders `C:\foo\abc\bar` and `C:\foo\xyz\bar`, but won't find a folder `C:\foo\abc\xyz\bar`. For the latter you need something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo' -Filter 'bar' -Directory -Recurse
```

If you have just a single variable folder level and want only files from the given path (without recursion) you can do something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo\*\bar\*' -File
```

If you also want all files in subfolders below `bar` use this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\foo\*\bar' -File -Recurse
```

Comment: I only need to put the * at a single level as shown in my question.  I tried: $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderName -File  and getting 0 files.  So that's why I doubed it was working.

Comment: Now it's working, not even 100% sure what I changed.  Maybe I didn't have the \*.* .  I was really interesting in the files, not the directoreis, just trying to determine if I need to filter directories before jumping to files.

Comment: Seems like when I added the Exclude it failed. $files = Get-ChildItem -Path $folderMask -Exclude "*_997_*.*"  -File.  I should have some files matching that don't have the exclude pattern in them.

Comment: Worked fine when I tested it, so I can't tell you why it doesn't work on your computer without seeing what exactly you're doing.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you want to find and return info about all files in all AS2FilesReceived directories for each folder under Vendors, then this might help you...

```
#Find all AS2FilesReceived directories
$dirs= Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\BizTalk\Vendors\*\AS2FilesReceived\' -Directory

#Return number of directories
"$($dirs.Count) directories found"

#Return list of directory names
$dirs | % {$_.Parent.Name}

#Return the full name of every text file under each directory
$dirs | % {Get-ChildItem -Path $_ *.txt} | % {$_.FullName}
```

Which returns...

```
3 directories found
Vendor1
Vendor2
Vendor3
C:\BizTalk\Vendors\Vendor1\AS2FilesReceived\Vendor1AS2File.txt
C:\BizTalk\Vendors\Vendor2\AS2FilesReceived\Vendor2AS2File.txt
C:\BizTalk\Vendors\Vendor3\AS2FilesReceived\Vendor3AS2File.txt
```